Why is there only a set amount of shockwaves when supersonic flow passes a curved surface?
In the picture below, why are there only 4 shockwaves created on the surface? Firstly, I'll label the shockwaves one to four.
So, the number 1 shockwave is the one furthest forward, and the number 4 shockwave is the one furthest back, so the last one.
If you look closely in between shock 1 and 2, the surface curves a small amount upward. Why, in this space between 1 and 2, is there no shockwave? Shouldn't there be an infinite amount of shockwaves there because every micrometer that the flow moves to the right the surface curves up by a small amount (presumably creating a shockwave)?

I'm assuming that all shockwaves in this picture are oblique shock waves, but I could be wrong.

I think you are misinterpreting the graphic...  Because why are there only three blue airflow arrows?

@MichaelHall That is a good point. Maybe it is just trying to give the viewer a general idea? If that is the case, it is kind of misleading.

Are the blue arrows misleading?  Do they make you think that there are only three streamlines?  Just because we misinterpret a figure does not mean it was misleading.  Sometimes it is our opportunity to learn.  More importantly, you are missing the point of the figure -- those are not shock waves (abrupt jump in compression).  Instead, those are 'Mach waves', a gentle gradual alternative to shock waves.

@RobMcDonald Yeah, maybe I was just misinterpreting it. So, if the flow is M > 1, then why aren't those shockwaves? Supersonic flow and a surface that turns should make a shockwave, right? My theory is that because maybe the amount of flow turning needed is so slight that only Mach waves need to form.

That is essentially correct.  Mach waves occur when a very small disturbance occurs or a very slight amount of turning.  In reality, we see this occur when there is some roughness on a surface, when a surface has a very gradual curved ramp, or (most commonly) due to shock-boundary layer interaction -- where the boundary layer acts like a somewhat soft boundary, causing the flow to turn gradually.
